# Redis messagebus vs. d-bus: what is happening at a low level? Basically the same thing?

Tags: redis, dbus, message-bus

I'm honestly surprised I haven't seen this discussed before. My impression is that Redis uses normal internet packet exchange to a server and gets the results back but that d-bus uses unix sockets (pipes) and superimposes a distribution system. 
I suppose I have the usual question as to which one is faster, but I would really like to know what's really going on when I pass messages with either of these two. There's probably going to be advantages to either. Can someone shed a little light?

Answer (score 3):

It's like discussing MQTT vs COM or SOAP vs QNX-IPC.

D-Bus has also a network mode that works over TCP. So on the low level it can be the same thing. But when using D-Bus locally, it doesn't involve network stack.

Redis has evolved from the plain sockets and weakly-structured databases, D-Bus - from the system services/objects and calls.

I think that the choice should be based on the high-level features. But that's too broad for StackOverflow.

Comment: I don't really know how either of them work, if you'd care to enlighten me. The only thing I really want to know is if Redis is fundamentally different than dbus for handling events, or are the two sort of the same approach. Their documentation doesn't really cover this. I'm not concerned about solving any particular problem. I want to understand what's going on.